# Artfacs on Volumetric clouds cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, volumetrics, artifacts

I'm trying to make a cloud with some displace, the first with a Voronoi and the second with a cloud, finishing it with a simple volume scatter shader, but when I'm rendering the cloud get same artifacts, it isn't occurring when I use only the Voronoi or cloud but when both are on this thing appear, I try something like turning up the max bounce value but made no difference, does someone know how to fix it?
[image: Render]
[image: Blender Print]

Comment: increase the volume bounces, as it is in very specific places (you can see the sligthly rounded shape the artifact creates) where it overlaps

Comment: ooh i could fix it, i forgot of this question, but it wad the subdivision surface the problem,the sequence of modifiers ware a 5 or six lvl ss> displace> displace, de ss was making the first displace too smooth and the second was deforming to mutch the mesh, than i put 3 lxl ss>displace>3 lvl  ss >displace